# Minecraft Recording doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, recording

When I try to record minecraft, any software I use produces a video file with the game sounds, but not my voice, and with no actual video, just a blank screen. I have tried many different programs, such as Fraps, Camtasia Studio, CamStudio, and a few others I can't remember. Any solution to this problem is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe CamStudio has an option (but I don't have it installed to check) for recording your mic.  In any case, many let's players use a second audio recording app for their mic, and then sync it up later.  I believe Mumble will work, but I know Audacity works.  Both are open source software.

Comment: Unless streaming live, MBraedly is right. Many people will overlay audio later. It allows for better audio mixing, and a much higher quality of sound. Not to mention avoids the accidental swearing when that Creeper inevitably sneaks up on you... Either way is definitely fine though with the right setup.

Comment: Do you mean that I record the video, and then have the video playing, and record audio then?

Comment: @MatthewNickson: With or without the video playing, but yes, record audio separately to the video stream. You can also record both at the same time (eg. recording audio via Mumble or Audacity while capturing game audio normally) though that takes a bit more setup to get going properly. The principle is that the more different streams you have, the better you can mix the audio manually. Is there a huge spike in the game audio because eg. a Creeper blew up behind you? That's fine, just tune down the game audio a little for those few seconds. You can't do that if everything is pre-muxed for you.

Comment: @MatthewNickson: No, you would record both at the same time.  If you take a look at one of [kurtjmac's videos](http://youtu.be/60a-9gLL-N0), you'll see that he makes a sync mark using a phrase at the beginning of the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [XSplit](http://www.xsplit.com/) successfully in the recent past. There were some issues with sound from other things (mumble specifically, I was playing multiplayer), but I believe that was due to my setup (I have speakers and headset with sounds going to each; XSplit doesn't seem to mux audio streams by default at least) rather than something to do with the program itself.

Comment: I'm just trying XSplit now. Everything's working fine so far.

Comment: Thanks! I've just looked up the tutorials for it, and everything works great.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This answer is FRAPS specific.*

The lack of video footage sounds like a codec issue. In particular, I've heard of and even experienced conflicts between the official DivX codec and FRAPS. Try updating the official audio codecs from your motherboard manufacturer or try [FFDshow](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/ffdshow.htm)

As for the lack of microphone audio in the recording, are you sure you have configured FRAPS to record your mic in addition to the game sounds? If not, you need to enable "record external input" under the sound capture settings. If your mic is properly installed, it should be listed on-screen.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any way of fixing the recording for Camtasia Studio? If not, I'll just switch to Fraps.

Comment: I believe Camtasia Studio depends on the same MPEG decoders as FRAPS, so I believe fixing any issues with your video drivers. As for the microphone audio, I found [this tutorial](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-system-audio-prior.html) which may be of help:

Comment: Also, I've removed the Realtek HD Audio solution from the answer, since that has nothing to do with your video codecs. Excuse my silliness; I haven't had much sleep.